# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2000\pi}\frac1{1+e^{\sin x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{2000\pi}\dfrac{1}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx$$

As $\dfrac{1}{1+e^{\sin x}}$ has period $\pi$

$$2000\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{1}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx$$

As $e^{\sin x}=e^{\sin(\pi-x)}$

$$4000\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{1}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx$$

$$I'=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{1}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx$$

$$I'=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{e^{-\sin x}}{1+e^{-\sin x}}dx$$
$$I'=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{1+e^{-\sin x}}{1+e^{-\sin x}}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-\sin x}}dx$$

$$I'=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{e^{\sin x}}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx$$

$$I''=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{e^{\sin x}}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx$$

$$I''=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{e^{\cos x}}{1+e^{\cos x}}dx$$

$$2I''=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{e^{\sin x}+e^{\sin x+\cos x}+e^{\cos x}+e^{\sin x+\cos x}}{(1+e^{\sin x})(1+e^{\cos x})}dx$$

Was not getting anywhere from here, so tried substitution in $I''$

$$e^{\sin x}=t$$
$$e^{\sin x}\cos x=\dfrac{dt}{dx}$$

$$\sin x=\ln(t)$$
$$\cos x=\sqrt{1-\ln^2t}$$
$$I''=\int_{1}^{e}\dfrac{dt}{(1+t)\sqrt{1-\ln^2t}}$$

Also doesn't seem any way to proceed from here.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Nitpick: $\frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{\sin x}}$ has period $2\pi$.

Comment: You also don't need to use the periodicity of that. Let $x= 2000\pi-t$ and since $\sin(2000\pi-t)=-\sin t$ you just need to add both the integrals and everything simplifies nicely as $\frac{1}{1+e^{\sin x}}+\frac{1}{1+e^{-\sin x}}=1$.

Comment: @EricTowers, my bad, thanks.

Comment: how to close this question?

Comment: @user3290550 : You could write a solution, mentioning Zacky's hint.

Comment: actually after realizing that period is $2\pi$, its all over. Its better to close or delete this question.

Comment: I'm afraid what I wrote above can't produce an answer as OP is asking for what went wrong, not for alternative solutions and it would be off-topic.// @user3290550 If you want it deleted then you can simply press the "delete" button, next to the "edit" one. As long as the post doesn't have answers it's fine to delete it.

Answer (score 6):

$$I=\int_{0}^{2000\pi}\frac{1}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx$$
$$\text{Since the periodicity  of the integrand is $2\pi$ we have:}$$
$$I=1000\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx$$
$$\Rightarrow I=1000\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx+1000\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx$$
$$\text{The substitution $x-\pi\to x$ in the second integral gives:}$$
$$I=1000\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx+1000\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1+e^{-\sin x}}dx$$
$$=1000\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx+1000\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{\sin x}}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx$$
$$=1000\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1+e^{\sin x}}{1+e^{\sin x}}dx=1000\pi$$